# Permission problem even the folder has 777

Tags: php, permissions

I have a problem with this code:

```
final public function logToSystem(string $message = '', string $anyName = '')

{
    if(!file_exists(PATH_ROOT . '/logs')) {
        mkdir(PATH_ROOT . '/logs', 777);
    }

    if(!is_writable(PATH_ROOT . '/logs/api_submissions_' . escapeshellarg($anyName) . '.log')) {
        throw new Exception('ABORTING! Can not write to file: ' . PATH_ROOT . '/logs/api_submissions_' . escapeshellarg($anyName) . '.log');
    }

    file_put_contents(PATH_ROOT . '/logs/api_submissions_apiAction.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

The /logs/ exists and has 777. I already set the ownership to www-data.

If I want to send any data to my API, I get this error:

```
[php7:error] [pid 544753] [client 12345:43019] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: ABORTING! Can not write to file: /var/www/html/logs/api_submissions_''.log in /var/www/html/admin/lib/controller/Controller_Admin_Articles.class.php:377\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/admin/lib/controller/Controller_Admin_Articles.class.php(492): Controller_Admin_Articles->logToSystem()\n#1 /var/www/html/core/lib/controller/Dispatcher.class.php(20): Controller_Admin_Articles->submitApiArticle()\n#2 /var/www/html/admin/index.php(7): Dispatcher::dispatch()\n#3 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/html/admin/lib/controller/Controller_Admin_Articles.class.php on line 377
```

Any idea?

Comment: `/var/www/html/logs/api_submissions_''.log` Your file name is not being created correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument of function `$anyName` should be changed before creating the file if it is an empty string

```
if ($anyName === '') {
    $anyName = time();
}
```

Or do some other logic to create a unique name

And also pay attention to `file_put_contents(PATH_ROOT . '/logs/api_submissions_apiAction.log', $message, FILE_APPEND);`  here you are not using the file name that was checked on write permission above this code

Also before if statement with `is_writable` function you should create the file if it is not exist, or add `file_exists` to if statement for addiional check (to be sure) if the file really exists. Otherwise `is_writable` function will always return false because the file does not exist in your filesystem. [Please check](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php)

I would suggest to have code like this

```
if(!file_exists(PATH_ROOT . '/logs')) {
    mkdir(PATH_ROOT . '/logs', 777);
}
if ($anyName === '') {
    $anyName = time(); // or any other file name, depends on your needs
}

$fileName = PATH_ROOT . '/logs/api_submissions_' . escapeshellarg($anyName) . '.log';
if(file_exists($fileName) && !is_writable($fileName)) {
    throw new Exception('ABORTING! Can not write to file: ' . $fileName);
}

file_put_contents($fileName, FILE_APPEND);
```